# phpmaker error generating files

Tags: php, mysql, windows, generador

**Hola a todos tengo un error que me arroja un programa cuando intento ejecutarlo.**

--> PHP MAKER **[WEB OFICIAL DEL PROGRAMA](https://phpmaker.dev/)**

> en resumen: el programa ayuda a generar codigo php muy rapido con
> BD..etc.

1)cuando tengo todo listo y perfecto pues le doy "click" a generar para obtener lo que necesito pero no genera nada porque da un error,no logro identificar el error ni encontrarlo buscando siquiera en la web y foro del programa

- solo he encontrado un video al respecto que se supone resuelve este error pero a mi no me ha funcionado.

****NOTA:** solo estoy curioseando el programa para decidirme si usarlo definitivamente a diario

- dejo adjunto URL del video donde (supuestamente) solucionan el error
  **[solucion - video referencia LINK AQUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l89SBh0SJO4&ab_channel=tomkris)**

****Este es:** el error que me tira el programa

[image: ADJUNTO IMAGEN AQUI DEL ERROR]

Comment: Pareciera no has satisfecho todos [los requerimientos](https://phpmaker.dev/download.php), especialmente Composer. Revisa también los otros que aparecen allí.

Comment: @aeportugal exactamente pienso lo mismo como que composer te esta dando error por que no tienes todo lo que las librerias requieren.